# Why are these figures taking multiple pages when they can be fitted in half the pages taken?

Tags: typography

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-A}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-B}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-C}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Why are these figures taking six pages while by visual inspection, we can fit two figures on one page?

Comment: your images are to big that can be fit two "figures" on page. Possible work arounds: (i) reduce image width or height, or  (ii) increase text area by use of the `geometry` package and try to fit all three image in figure into one row. Also, if you have successive figures, you can merge for example two in one `figure` float, where each has own caption.

Comment: they don't fit. I had to extend the height by 3.5cm. Try with `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\advance\textheight by 3.5cm`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can i do this only on certain pages?

Comment: you could add `\vspace{-1cm}` at the begin of the first figure, and `\vspace{-3cm}` at the end of the second. Then they will fit on a page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This doesn't work

Comment: it works. I tried in your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Strange, its not working for me..

Comment: Please, remember that TeX is case sensitive and it won't find `example-image-A` on a case sensitive filesystem (you're probably using Windows). Anyway, if I merge the first two `figure` environments, I get a vertical overfull of about 86pt, that means 3cm. Reduce the size of the subfigures.

Comment: @egreg, How can I do that?

Comment: @Math Use a different factor than `0.475\textwidt`.

Comment: Problem solved? If yes then consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to fit two figures per page.

Note, if a float is already accepted as [htb] it will not be converted to [p] when the next figure arrives.  That can only happen if both are on the queue at the start of a page, or a `\clearpage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.475\linewidth}% default is [b]
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.475\linewidth}
    \caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}%{1SAIRSI.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}%{1SAIRSII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.475\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}%{1SAIRSIII.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.475\linewidth}
        \caption{Plot of system (4.1)-(4.4) with $\beta_A=0.2$, $\beta_I=0.1$, $b=0.55$, $\mu=0.01$, $\nu=0.8$, $\rho=0.1$, $\xi =0.001$, $\gamma_A =0.15$, $\gamma_I=0.1$, $\sigma=0.2$, $\eta=0.7$ and $\alpha=0.01$  hence $\mathcal{R}_0 \approx 0.9265$.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Just for fun, here is a demo on the effects of the positioning options for subfigure.  The red lines show the baseline location.

[image: subfigure positioning options]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
        
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{1in}
First Baseline\strut

default

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{1in}
First Baseline\strut

[t]

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{1in}
First Baseline\strut

[c]

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{1in}
First Baseline\strut

[b]

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{subfigure}[T]{1in}
First Baseline\strut

[T]

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\begin{subfigure}[B]{1in}
First Baseline\strut

[B]

Last Baseline\strut
\end{subfigure}\llap{\color{red}{\rule{1in}{0.5pt}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```